# strlen of char* malloc

Tags: malloc, strlen

I have the following code

```
char *new_str;
int size_in_bytes;
int length;

size_in_bytes = 2*sizeof(char);
new_str = (char *)malloc(size_in_bytes);
length = strlen(new_str);
```

Expecting the length to be 2, actually it is 16.
Can someone explain why?

Comment: This code is reading beyond allocated memory and can result in undefined behavior

Comment: Use `calloc()`, then you'll get the right answer (which should be 0).  There's no (portable) way to determine the size of an allocated block (unless there's something new in the latest standard).

Answer (score 5):

strlen() returns the index of the first null-byte ('\0'), starting from the address you pass it. Strings in C typically always end with this character, to mark the end of the string.

strlen() does not return the length of the actual block of memory.

In your example the memory is uninitialized, and strlen() is reading past the end of your block of memory and into other parts of your program's heap, until it finds a null-byte.